# Neo4j or SQLite to hold a folder structure?

Tags: java, sqlite, neo4j

I need to make an app in Java that must add in a database all the files (with folder structure) from a hard drive.
I need to add the metadata of this files as well.

What it will be the best aproach ? Using SQLite with multiple tables or Neo4j ??

Answer (score 2):

A file system is represented as a tree. A [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29) is in fact an undirected graph.

While this question may be flagged as opinions based, I would love to add some points valuable to Neo4j.

Your file structure will be represented naturally in a graph, which means you will not have (or mostly not) differences between your domain and what is persisted in your database.

Secondly, Neo4j is really performant in matter of ACL, which is part of your metadata. http://maxdemarzi.com/2013/03/18/permission-resolution-with-neo4j-part-1/

So all your points are in fact a "graph" and thus Neo4j is the most valuable choice for fulfilling your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

**I think it depends on what kind of operations will you do on such data.**:

But generally speaking Neo4j is very useful if you would need to traverse the directories and search for the files. Neo4j allows you to create a very easy query and iterate over the results in a friendly Java API.